# How much height is required for an American green tree frog habitat?

Tags: containment, terrariums, frogs, amphibians

I'm looking to start a terrestrial frog terrarium that, ideally, wouldn't be higher than 1 - 1.5 feet (2.5 feet wide, 1 foot deep are hard limits).

[American green tree frogs](http://exoticpets.about.com/cs/frogsandtoads/a/amertreefrogs.htm) seem like a good candidate, but is that enough height for them to be happy and not feel claustrophobic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

American green tree frogs stay relatively small. I would say you could go with a relatively small tank. 5 gallon would work but a 10 gallon would be ideal more than likely. The standard 10 gallon tanks are around the specifications that you listed in your question and definitely best as you'll be able to add more to the tank like hides. You'll know if the little guy is stressed out. [These](http://www.zillarules.com/all-products/terrariums/critter-cage) are what I sell at the pet shop I work at. Find a store near you to snag one!